# Django IIS Deployment - HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found

Tags: python, django, iis

I need explanation on how to deploy Django Application on Windows IIS Server.

I am struggling to follow the following [tutorial](https://blog.nonstopio.com/deploy-django-application-on-windows-iis-server-93aee2864c41)

I have a project which looks like this :

```
[My_App]
--> [My_App_Venv]
--> [abcd]
    |-> manage.py
    |-> [abcd]
        |->  settings.py
        |-> [static]
        |-> ...
```

> **[** example **]** is used to represent folders

I Need to understand how I should setup my IIS website :

### What should be FastCGI Application settings

Full Path :

```
C:\xxxxx\My_App\My_App_Venv\Scripts\python.exe
```

Arguments :

```
C:\xxxxx\My_App\My_App_Venv\Lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py
```

**Environment Variables :**

```
 1. DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE : abcd.settings             (I think this is ok)
 2. PYTHONPATH             : C:\xxxxx\My_App           (I am not sure about this)
 3. WSGI_HANDLER           : abcd.wsgi.application     (I think this is ok)
```

### Create and Configure a New IIS Web Site

what should be the physical Path  ?

```
C:\xxxxx\My_App ? 
C:\xxxxx\My_App\abcd ? 
C:\xxxxx\My_App\abcd\abcd ?
```

### Configure the mapping module ## (which i assume is correct)

```
Request path: *
Module: FastCgiModule
Executable : C:\xxxxx\My_App\My_App_Venv\Scripts\python.exe|C:\xxxxx\My_App\My_App_Venv\Lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py
Name  : Django Handler
```

---

output

[image]

Hope someone can help to understand what I am doing wrong, I might use wrong path somewhere.

Note : When I do By hand :

```
cd C:/xxxxx/My_App/My_App_Venv
.\\scripts\Activate
cd..
cd abcd
python manage.py runserver
```

The website is well displayed on : http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Comment: 1. Use HttpPlatformHandler. 2. Don’t use virtual environment.

Comment: @LexLi Why should I not use Venv ?

Comment: When you try to apply the proper file access permissions, Python virtual environment will give you all the headaches.

Comment: @LexLi and I should use `HttpPlatformHandler` instead of what ?

Comment: You should try to host Python web apps on Linux if possible. And when you really need them on IIS/Windows, FastCGI isn't recommended as wfastcgi is deprecated. I provided an example on Flask, but Django isn't much different, https://halfblood.pro/running-flask-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/

Comment: I also struggled to deploy Django & Flask apps on IIS but I managed to deploy them don't know how I gave right permissions but it worked. I'll suggest watching this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=APCQ15YqqQ0) it helped me while deploying it has [Github](https://github.com/Johnnyboycurtis/webproject?tab=readme-ov-file#microsoft-iis) link for code snippets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many reasons for this error, you can try the following methods to solve the problem:

1. Changing the Application Pool from Classic to Integrated fixed the issue.
2. Try removing and adding the service back in IIS.

If the problem still cannot be solved, try using failed request tracing to see details about 404 error, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.

Comment: Not sure why this was accepted, but 1) classic/integrated pipeline modes are only relevant to ASP.NET, not anything else (like Python). 2) What were you referring to as "the service"? Though the FRT part should be helpful.